# Why can't I set the permalink of a custom 404 page to /404?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

When I set the custom 404 error to point to a custom 404 page named "404", it gets the job done and displays this page when it should correctly.

[image]

I'm just curious why am I not able to set the permalink of that page to /404/? It forces it to 404-2, but I don't have any other permalinks set to /404, and the /404 page does not exist when I navigate directly to that URL. Is it some kind of a reserved permalink maybe? Do I need to remove the original WP 404.php page from the server or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. WP adds `-2` to numeric permalink. Not mentioned on [Using Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/).

Comment: I think it comes from [wp_unique_post_slug](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/).